# NodeJS OSX Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm creating a server with: `const server = require('http').createServer();`

Creating const io `const io = require('socket.io')(server);`

And doing server.listen();

```
var port = 4000;
server.listen(port);
```

But I'm getting this error and after a few hours searching and trying things I'm here on stackoverflow to ask here.

[image: terminal]

Things I have tried include:

Clearing port by using `lsof -i tcp:4000` to get process but it didn't return anything,
Restarting computer,
Changing port,
Reinstalling node,
Updating node and,
Running as administrator

It used to work, but after restarting my computer the next day this happened.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean with _"clearing port"_?

Comment: @robertklep I have modified the question to provide more details.

Comment: Behind a proxy?

Comment: `EPERM` suggests UNIX domain sockets (or possibly, some sort of firewall or anti-virus-type software). Try `server.listen(Number(port))`.

Answer (score 0):

The error code is EPERM which means your port 4000 is locked. You can find the process causing it by using the command below for OSX El Capitan and above.

```
lsof -i tcp:4000
```

Comment: Do you mean `lsof -i tcp:4000`?

Comment: It doesn't return anything

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, copy pasted from somewhere else and I forgot to modify

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that Norton was blocking Node so I had to remove Node from the Norton application allowing list and re-add it.